# Visualisation of trunk, branches, and tags of an SVN project

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, subversive, svnkit

Is there a tool or plugin for Eclipse that I can use for visualising the different SVN versions of my Java project (trunk, branches, and tags) along with the respective dates and names.

I am looking for something like this: [image: here]

Comment: Do you wanna get 'lemme google that for you' link or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned TortoiseSVN; it isn't an Eclipse plug-in, but with that tool you can quite easily retrieve this information pointing to the root of your SVN respoitory.
The root contains those three directories: `trunk`, `branches` and `tags`.

Than, using the `revision graph` tool you can view something similar to your pic.

Comment: thank you @Andrea I will check the revision graph option

Comment: It won't work for the image given. It looks like the desired result will show merges from one branch to another. This is a feature that has been requested a few times in TortoiseSVN's revision graph and the developers have pretty much said it will never happen because it would be too slow. There is a command-line tool, `svn mergeinfo` http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.mergeinfo.html